# karrigell import my own module

Tags: python, web, import, cheetah

i'm new in karrigell, but i got problem when i was trying to use the phase

```
    from testmodule import TestClass
```

where the "testmodule" is my own module and TestClass is the only class defined inside the module.

but when i was going to the site, i got the error as

```
    ImportError: No module named testmodule
```

i went to google and got a possible solution as:

```
    tc = Import("testmodule")
```

this is ok. but how could i import the class instead of importing the module. the "from ... import ..." is not availbale anymore in Karrigell?

appreciate your help!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Karrigell so there might be a better way to do this, but here is what I have found. Let's say you have a file called "Classes.py" and you want to use ClassA and ClassB inside of that file. I have found that
    `Classes = Import("path/to/Classes")` and 
    `x = Classes.ClassA()`
will let you create instances of the classes you defined in the module. I will update this if I find any additional information. Cheers